# How to find distinct values from System.Data.DataTableCollection

Tags: c#, datatable

I need to find distinct values from a data table collection, I tried as following
but getting error as "cannot convert from 'System.Data.DataTableCollection' to 'System.Data.DataTable'"

Here's my code

```
 DataView view = new DataView(this.excelBook.Tables);
 DataTable distinctValues = view.ToTable(true, "DataSourceName");
```

What is the best method to do this?

Comment: Maybe it is `view.DefaultView.ToTable`

Comment: See this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataset-datatable-dataview/creating-a-datatable-from-a-dataview